# remove tab from TabLayoutPanel programly , GWT

Tags: java, gwt

i need an idea how to remove tab if Button within this tab has been clicked.

thx.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `ClickHandler` to the button, and have it call one of the [remove](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabPanel.html) methods (either the one that takes an int or the one that takes the tab's widget) with an argument that corresponds to the tab that it's on.